# Pass spring locale variable to application.properties

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

There are URLs I have put in my application.properties file. Now these URLs need to have the language so that the page loads in different languages. For example in my application.properties file I have a property for the Contact Us link as below

> contact_us_link=https://my-domain.com/{locale}/contact-us

In the above link I need to use the current application locale so that if the locale is "en", the above property will become

> contact_us_link=https://my-domain.com/**en**/contact-us

How can I use my locale variable in the property file?

PS: The above property will be accessed in Thymeleaf as shown below

```
<li>
<a th:href="@{${@environment.getProperty('contact_us_link')}}" th:text="#{footer.contactUs.text}">Contact Us</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the fellow stackoverflow users, I found a simple solution for the above question from the Thymeleaf documentation.

In my **application.properties** file I used the property as below

> contact_us_link=https://my-domain.com/{locale}/contact-us

In my html **${@environment.getProperty('contact_us_link')}** to get the url from the application properties file and additionally I pass the value corresponding to the **{locale}** in the url as shown below

```
<li>
<a th:href="@{${@environment.getProperty('contact_us_link')}(locale=${locale.toLowerCase()})}" th:text="#{footer.contactUs.text}">Contact Us</a>
</li>
```

I can access the current locale using **${locale}** variable in Thymeleaf templates.

Below is the link to the official documentation

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `application.properties` for this, you should probably use internationalization (i18n) using message bundles (`messages.properties`).

If you have a limited amount of languages, you can create a separate properties  file for each language, for example:

- `messages.properties`: Default/fallback
- `messages_en.properties`: English translated properties
- `messages_de.properties`: German translated properties

If each of these files contains a `contact_us_link` property, Spring will automatically resolve them. In your Thymeleaf template you should use the following:

```html
<small th:text="#{contact_us_link}"></small>
```

Alternatively, if you need a more dynamic approach, you can remove the property from all your localized `message_*.properties` files and use a placeholder within the `messages.properties` file, for example:

```html
contact_us_link=https://my-domain.com/{0}/contact-us
```

Now you can pass the locale as a substitution in your template:

```html
<a th:href="#{contact_us_link(locale)}">Contact us</a>
```

---

If you really need to use `application.properties`, you'll have to do the substitution by yourself. Luckily, you can use everything SpEL has to offer within your template, so you could create your own bean:

```java
@Component
public class Formatter {
    public String format(String message, Object... variables) {
        return MessageFormat.format(message, variables);
    }
}
```

And now you could substitute it using this bean:

```html
<a th:href="${@formatter.format(@environment.getProperty('contact_us_link'), #locale)}">Contact us</a>
```

Comment: This is not about rendering a text. This is about redirecting to the correct link. the link has to be dynamic because the locale changes. Please understand the question properly

Comment: @simplelenz Actually, I understood the question, but the question didn't mention how dynamic that it should be. Without knowing that, I just posted a possible solution that could work depending on the amount of locales waiting for a response if this would work in your case or not. That's also why I used "limited amount of languages" to create a context to put my answer into. I've now updated my answer. While this isn't the perfect use case for message bundles, message bundles do allow you to use substitutions while application properties do not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that spring will provide/translate locale while fetching property in thymeleaf. Rather you can make different keys for each locale and fetch them accordingly.

```
contact_us_link_en = https://my-domain.com/en/contact-us
```

Use ${#locale} while fetching property in thymeleaf.

Comment: Yes this is possible but there has to be a better solution