# How parametrize link value in spring controller and thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have two methods mapping "/cars/new" and "/used_cars":

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/cars")
public class CarsController {

    @GetMapping("/new")
    public String getNewCars() {      
        return "new_cars";
    }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UsedCarsController {

    @GetMapping("/used_cars")
    public String getUsedCars() {        
        return "used_cars";
    }
}
```

Then I use same link values in html(thymeleaf):

```
<nav>
  <a th:href="@{/cars/new}">new cars</a> |
  <a th:href="@{/used_cars}">used cars</a> 
</nav>
```

How I can parametrize values of "/cars/new" and "/used_cars" in some *.properties file to avoid Repeat Yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use properties to solve this question. Define a property in application.properties

```
get.mapping.path=/new
```

And then use the property in your mapping

```java
@GetMapping("${get.mapping.path}")
public String getNewCars() {      
    return "new_cars";
}
```

The [Thymeleaf-docu](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html) can explain you how to access these properties from your templates:

```xml
<nav>
  <a th:href="${@environment.getProperty('get.mapping.path')}">new cars</a>
</nav>
```

If you need internationalization support, this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50720604/pass-spring-locale-variable-to-application-properties#answer-50720767) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-placeholders) :

> Patterns in @RequestMapping annotations support ${…​} placeholders against local properties and/or system properties and environment variables. This may be useful in cases where the path a controller is mapped to may need to be customized through configuration. For more information on placeholders, see the javadocs of the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer class.

Some it would be something like this :

```
@RequestMapping("${endpoint.newcars}")
```

This property should be declared in your application.properties or application.yml file

```
endpoint.newcars=/cars/new
```

For the Thymleaf part you can access your properties use :

```
${@environment.getProperty('endpoint.newcars')}
```